# Error using eazfuscator.net v3.3.0 Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program

Tags: c#, eazfuscator

Using eazfuscator.net 3.3.0 I'm having this error: "Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program" This happens when i put the mouse cursor over a datagridview. I'm using C # in visual studio 2010.

Another error is that compiling the application using eazfuscator does not start if it is not run as an administrator.

any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Does the issue occur if you don't use eazfuscator ?

Comment: No, when compiling the application without eazfuscator everything is fine. Everything is perfect. It is only when I use the eazfuscator to obfuscate the layer where the forms are.

Comment: I suspect you want to raise a support issue with eazfuscator.

Comment: I've thought the same thing but the eazfuscator version I'm using is 3.3.0. That is free. One data that does not supply is that datagride are using validating and validated events. Could there be a way to exclude them and not be obfuscate?

Comment: That error is a strong indication of unverifiable code that is present in the assembly after obfuscation. There were several bugs in Eazfuscator.NET that might lead to this. The good news is that all known issues were rectified in newer Eazfuscator.NET versions.

Comment: Thank you very much. that's true.